# How do I get the full name of a user in .net MVC 3 intranet app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC 3 intranet application that performs windows authentication against a particular domain. I would like to render the current user's name.

in the view,

```
@User.Identity.Name
```

is set to `DOMAIN\Username`, what I want is their full `Firstname Lastname`

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```cs
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    var principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, User.Identity.Name);
    var firstName = principal.GivenName;
    var lastName = principal.Surname;
}
```

You'll need to add a reference to the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` assembly.

You can add a Razor helper like so:

```cs
@helper AccountName()
    {
        using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
    {
        var principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, User.Identity.Name);
        @principal.GivenName @principal.Surname
    }
}
```

If you indend on doing this from the view, rather than the controller, you need to add an assembly reference to your web.config as well:

```
<add assembly="System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement" />
```

Add that under `configuration/system.web/assemblies`.

Comment: I just tried to implement the razor helper and <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement" /> is throwing an error (can't find the reference), but using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement works from C# files and the dll is included in the project references, any ideas?

Comment: Figured it out, had to set the "copy local" property of the DLLs to true. :)

Comment: For MVC4, web.config needs `<add namespace="System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement" />` in `configuration/system.web/pages/namespaces`.

Comment: Hey...this worked for me .. I was having a verison inside this, <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement" /> and had all issue. After removing the version all good.

Answer (score 7):

Another option, without requiring a helper... You could just declare context and principal before you need to utilize these values, and then utilize it like a standard output...

```
@{ // anywhere before needed in cshtml file or view
    var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
    var principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, User.Identity.Name);
}
```

Then anywhere within the document, just call each variable as needed:

```
@principal.GivenName // first name
@principal.Surname // last name
```

Comment: This is essentially the same answer as the previous one, but not requiring a helper is a plus in my opinion, so I like your answer better. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you have many controllers then using @vcsjones approach might be painfull.
Therefore I'd suggest creating extension method for TIdentity.

```
public static string GetFullName(this IIdentity id)
    {
        if (id == null) return null;

        using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
        {
            var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, id.Name);
            return userPrincipal != null ? $"{userPrincipal.GivenName} {userPrincipal.Surname}" : null;
        }
    }
```

And then you can use it in your view:

```
<p>Hello, @User.Identity.GetFullName()!</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've upgraded to Identity 2 and are using claims, then this kind of info would be a claim. Try creating an extension method:

```
public static string GetFullName(this IIdentity id)
{
    var claimsIdentity = id as ClaimsIdentity;

    return claimsIdentity == null 
        ? id.Name 
        : string.Format("{0} {1}", 
            claimsIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.GivenName).Value, 
            claimsIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Surname).Value);
}
```

Then you can use it in the view like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.GetFullName() + "!", "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
```

Comment: Hi @Sinaesthetic. Could you pass me some link which explains ClaimsIdentity from the scartch up?

Answer (score 0):

Add the below in your _ViewImports.cshtml page :

```
@using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
```

Then, in your _Layouts.cshtml place the below :

```
@{ 
var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
var principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, User.Identity.Name);}
```

Note: You can concatenate by creating additional variable ex:

```
var userName = @principal.Givenname + ", " + @principal.Surname;
```

You can not call the variable 'userName' directly, however, you can call 'userName' anywhere on the page by creating a hidden field.