# Cannot load System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement in ASP.NET VB site

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, directoryservices, account-management

I have been working on adding Active Directory functionality to an already existing ASP.NET website following this guide by Microsoft: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326340. It's been a long process, but what I'm stuck on now is not being able to access the AccountManagement class to use certain functions such as "GetGroup()".

I can access DirectoryServices just fine, but not Account Management. When I use the following code to test the reference:

```
Response.Write(System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.Principal.GetGroups())
```

I get this error: BC30456: 'AccountManagement' is not a member of 'DirectoryServices'.

I have already added this assembly tag to the web.config page:

```
<add assembly="System.DirectoryServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
```

Also I am importing both namespaces:

```
<%@ Import Namespace="System.DirectoryServices" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement" %>
```

And this is my version info that shows on the error page:

> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34237

I'm editing this website in VS 2010. What am I missing and how can I get AccountManagement added here? Am I not importing it properly, or is there somewhere I can check to see if there is a missing .dll?

Comment: For me, not valid using `<%@ Assembly Name="System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement" %>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although you're importing both namespaces in the markup, you only reference `System.DirectoryServices.dll`. The AccountManagement part is in a separate dll.

Add another reference to web.config:

```
<add assembly="System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement ...
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think that reference could be added there, but I hadn't checked the "Add Reference..." option since updating the site to using ASP.NET 4.0.

Comment: The line of code can now get as far as the "GetGroups()" Before triggering this error now:

BC30469: Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.

Comment: @justanotherguy, you are calling `GetGroups()` as if it were a static method (and 'static' in C# means the same as 'shared' in VB.Net). However it is an instance method, so you'll need a Principal **object** before you can call this method. And in fact because Principal is abstract, the **object** will have to be an instance of a (non-abstract) subclass, e.g. UserPrincipal. And then GetGroups() will give you the Groups to which that user belongs.

Answer (score 5):

I tried as suggested by Reg Edit, but then I had another error in which my application couldn't find the reference described in the web.config. After a few hours, I came across [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8900820/1589379).

It says that the reference to **System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement** should have "Copy local" on '*True*'. Honestly, I see no reason why that should work, because that is a Framework library, but changing that setting worked for me.

> You can do something like this:
>
> ```cs
> using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
> {
>     var principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, User.Identity.Name);
>     var firstName = principal.GivenName;
>     var lastName = principal.Surname;
> }
> ```
>
> You'll need to add a reference to the
>   `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` assembly.
>
> You can add a Razor helper like so:
>
> ```cs
> @helper AccountName()
>     {
>         using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
>     {
>         var principal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, User.Identity.Name);
>         @principal.GivenName @principal.Surname
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> If you indend on doing this from the view, rather than the controller,
>   you need to add an assembly reference to your web.config as well:
>
> ```
> <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement" />
> ```
>
> Add that under `configuration/system.web/assemblies`.

From: [Answer To: How do I get the full name of a user in .net MVC 3 intranet app?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8900820/1589379)