# How do I display full name in ASP.NET MVC 5 app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MS web apps...

Visual Studio 2015 - ASP.NET MVC 5.2.3

I have found numerous solutions online for older MVC apps but I can't get any to work.  Specifically this one:
[How do I get the full name of a user in .net MVC 3 intranet app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8900678/how-do-i-get-the-full-name-of-a-user-in-net-mvc-3-intranet-app)
Should that solution work in MVC 5?

I have added a reference to System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement, and set local copy to true.

I have this in my HomeController:

```
    public string firstName;
    public string lastName;

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "MFAD"))
        {
            UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, User.Identity.Name);
            firstName = user.GivenName;
            lastName = user.Surname;
        }

        return View();
    }
```

How do I add the helper?
I want the name to appear for all pages, do I implement this in __Layout.cshtml?

Comment: Are `firstName` and `lastName` the values your expect? To display then in the layout, you can use `@{ Html.RenderAction(....); }` to call a controller method that return a partial view containing those values in a view model

Comment: Yes first and last names.  I am not sure how to implement that, but I will see what I can do.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you wanna display the name on all your page, I think it would be a rather bad idea to do a db call (which is what the razor helper does) on all your pages.

And I don't like razor helpers to make db calls too...

You should rather do this query after a successful login (I guess you have a Login and a Logout action), and store that value in a session.

Something like that.

```
public ActionResult Login(...) {
    //check if the login is correct, if yes
   using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "MFAD"))
        {
            UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, User.Identity.Name);
            firstName = user.GivenName;
            lastName = user.Surname;
            HttpContext.Current.Session["currentUser"] = firstName + " " + lastName;
        }
```

Than you can use `HttpContext.Current.Session["currentUser"]` in your _Layout.cshtml, with some null check.

Of course, in your LogOut method, you should also do a
`HttpContext.Current.Session["currentUser"] = null;`

Comment: This is using windows authentication, in a intranet environment.  I am getting an error on HttpContext.Current.Session, red line under current. 'HttpContextBase' does not contain a definition for 'Current' and no extension method 'Current' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpContextBase' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: You may try `System.Web.HttpContext.Current`

Comment: That doesn't work for me either.  I assume you meant for me to add that as a "using" statement??

Comment: No, the using would be `using System.Web`

Comment: So how would I modify the original code you posted?   HttpContext.Current.Session["currentUser"] = firstName + " " + lastName; errors out for me.  How/where do I use System.Web.HttpContext.Current?

Comment: Well, just add System.Web in the start ? So `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["currentUser"] = firstName + " " + lastname;` Be sure that you have a reference to System.Web assembly in your project, of course.

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses I didn't get back to this until a bit ago.  I go your suggestion to work.  I had an obvious typo after I looked at it long enough.  This is working!

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement to your project and do it like this...

```
    using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        UserPrincipal userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.Current;
        var name = userPrincipal.GivenName + " " + userPrincipal.Surname;

        return View();
    }
```